# How to add a column with the column-names of the value in the row?

Tags: r, match, cbind

My question may not be so well formulated and sounds complicated. But what I want is very simple.
From the given Data frame **Df** I have made a new Data frame **Df1** which contains the **max values** ​​from each individual column.
Now I want to add to my new data frame Df1 a column with the name of each column from which the max value comes.

I have prepared an example for this.

```
A <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)
B <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)
C <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)
D <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)
E <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)
F <- runif(5,min = 0.1, max = 3)

Car <- c("Audi","BMW","Mercedes","Ford","Opel")

Df<-data.frame(Car,A,B,C,D,E,F)

Df1<-Df%>%
  group_by(Car)%>%
  summarize(max.value = max(A,B,C,D,E,F))
```

**Df:**

[image]

**Df1:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>%
   transmute(Car, max.value = pmax(!!! .[-1]), 
             rowName = names(.)[-1][max.col(.[-1])])
```